# Which user should own the directory where lives the website?

Tags: http, nginx, chown

I have nginx running with a master process as root and worker process as www-data.
Which user should own the root dirctory of the website (/var/www/html), and what permission (rwx) should the directory and its content have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have below permission for root directory.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 612 Mar 27  2018 xyz.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  21 Nov 27  2019 phpinfo.php
```